# Copy lines removed from text files back into their original files with bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, github

In a GitHub repository I have a hundred or so autogenerated files with a comment header that specifies things such as date-generated, version, etc.

The trouble is that more often than not the header changes but the actual useful contents of the files don't change.
When this happens GitHub reports a hundred or so changed files while in reality maybe only a couple have changed. This makes it very hard to spot the real changes.

Unfortunately these headers must be present at release time for reasons that are not relevant to the issue at hand. Otherwise I would just strip them out and be done with it.

To work around this issue my plan is to:

1. Strip the comment headers from the files and save them into a separate file before committing them to the repository.
2. Reincorporate the headers into the files at release time as a step in a Jenkins pipeline.

For the first part of the plan I am stripping the first 5 lines of the files and saving them into a single versions.txt file.

The original files (*.h) I am working on all have a format like

```
/* Some comment */
/* More useless text */
/* Version of the file */
/* Maybe a date */
/* More comment */

Actual useful file content
```

I use the following command

```bsh
head -5 *.h > versions.txt && sed -i '1,+4d' *.h
```

to remove the first 5 lines from each file and create a versions.txt file that ends up looking like this:

```
==> File1.h <==
/* Some comment */
/* More useless text */
/* Version of the file */
/* Maybe a date */
/* More comment */

==> File2.h <==
/* Some comment */
/* More useless text */
/* Version of the file */
/* Maybe a date */
/* More comment */

==> File3.h <==
/* Some comment */
/* More useless text */
/* Version of the file */
/* Maybe a date */
/* More comment */
```

I would now like to find the way to revert the process and put each set of lines back into it's respective original file.

A better alternative would be to find a way for GitHub to ignore the first 5 lines of the files, but as far as I've been able to tell this is not possible.

Comment: Why did you **remove** them then, instead of simply **copying** the information you needed?

Comment: I removed them because I need to, in GitHub they create a whole bunch of changes that annoy the developers.
But at release time I want to put them back with my Jenkins pipeline.

Comment: THIS is obvious, but WHY did you remove them, if you need them back afterwards???

Comment: Sorry, I misread why for how.I removed them because I need to, in GitHub they create a whole bunch of changes that annoy the developers. But at release time I want to put them back with my Jenkins pipeline.

Comment: For example some of the comments I remove contain the date and time at which the file was autogenerated BUT the useful contents of the file remain the same.
The objective is for GitHub to not tell me that 1000 files have changed when the only thing that changed is the date and time in the header part that I want to strip.

Comment: Well, then the you need to proceed like I commented it above. If you get stuck at a certain step, please show the code you have written up to this point and tell us where the exact problem is. Also explain the context (i.e. that you are working with Github) in your question. Maybe there is a way to tell Gitub to ignore comments for certain languages. I don't have much experience with github and can't judge this straight out of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
 awk '/^==>/ { cnt=1;filname=$2 } { print "sed -i \""cnt"i "$0"\" "filname;cnt++ }' version.txt
```

This search for lines beginning with "==>" and sets the second space delimited field to a variable filname. This proceeding lines up until the next "==>" are then used to create a sed command to insert the lines at the top of the file, using cnt to terack where in the file to insert the lines.

Once you are happy that the above command prints sed commands as expected (VERY IMPORTANT!) you can then action the commands with awk's system function and so:

```
 awk '/^==>/ { cnt=1;filname=$2 } { system("sed -i \""cnt"i "$0"\" "filname);cnt++ }' version.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Raman Sailopal's answer hit the mark except for a couple of details:

1. The command would also insert the `==> Filename <==` line generated by the stripping command `head -5 *.h > versions.txt && sed -i '1,+4d' *.h`
2. The command would not insert empty lines.
3. The command worked on the extra empty line that is inserted by the original stripping command as a separator between files.

I therefore expanded the provided command with `if` statements so that it

1. only operates when `cnt > 1 && cnt < 7` making it work on exactly five lines while disregarding the first `==> Filename <==` line.
2. Inserts empty lines with `sed -i 1G` when needed.
   Here is the full command I ended up with:

```
awk '/^==>/ { cnt=1;filename=$2 } 
{ if(cnt > 1 && cnt < 7 && $0 == "") system("sed -i \""cnt-1"G\" " filename)} 
{ if(cnt > 1 && cnt < 7 && $0 != "") system("sed -i \""cnt-1"i "$0"\" "filename);cnt++}' versions.txt
```